# IAP на юнити. После покупки не дает выбрать

Tags: unity3d, playmarket

У меня реализованы покупки по IAP. При покупке расходуемых товаров проблем нет. Но при покупке скина например, пользователь покупает, но после выбрать не может ибо выбор и покупка на одной кнопке. Можно ли как-то это решить? Или нужно менять интерфейс и добавлять вторую кнопку.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляйте кнопку для выбора.

Сохраняйте статус покупки скина в булевой переменной к примеру `firstSkinPurchased`, и если статус купленный то открываете вторую кнопку с выбором.